# How can I get specific data from HTML in React?

Tags: html, reactjs, components, jsx

I'm fetching an API that responds a preformatted HTML file with a style tag with CSS props, and most importantly, ID tags defined where there is information that I need to extract, to paint a different React UI Component, than the horrible HTML I am getting, which is currently being rendered with html-react-parser as iframe.

```
<div class="App" style="text-align: center;">
    <h1 #text1_to_extract>html-react-parser</h1>
    <p >
      <a
        href="https://github.com/remarkablemark/html-react-parser"
        target="_blank"
        rel="noopener noreferrer"
        #text2_to_extract
      >
        View GitHub repository
      </a>
    </p>
    <hr class="remove">
  </div>
```

How can I extract the text inside this *#id* and parse directly to a JSX tag?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
const collection = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
const idText = collection[0].id;
```

In the idText variable, you will find the textinside the id.